# Android 4.4 sdcard access new rules: about saving a file that started an activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-sdcard, android-4.4-kitkat

I read that with Android 4.4 there are new rules for saving files on sdcard by apps.
I have a specific case to ask about:

- an app (activity) A starts another app (activity) B feeding it with a file:// url, say it's a txt file (B is a text editor);
- the app B opens the file and edits it.

Is the called app B able to save the edited content on the same file? Or will the new rules prevent it?

Comment: **"I read that with Android 4.4 there are new rules for saving files on sdcard by apps."** : It would be useful if you posted a link to where you read that.

Comment: @Squonk here for example: http://www.xda-developers.com/android/android-l-may-change-sd-card-access-rules/

Comment: The new rules will prevent it. Use a content provider. Well if the editer supports it. Easier to use external memory.

Comment: @greenapps Are you saying that external_sd is not affected by the new rules?

Comment: There are three types of memory: internal memory, external memory and memory on removable media (like micro SD card). On some devices external and removable media is the same. De discussion here was about removable media.

Comment: @greenapps in Android sdcard doesn't mean removable storage, instead it is where downloads, documents, music, pictures (and so on) folders are. I mean /mnt/sdcard folder, it's neither internal memory nor removable, if I'm right, provided that the user does not tear his/her device apart to see the real "sdcard" sdcard inside. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes. In some devices /sdcard is the removable micro SD card. In other devices it is external memory.

Comment: @greenapps Thank you for pointing this out. So /mnt/external_sd if affected by the new rules as /mnt/sdcard is, I guess.

Comment: If you have both in one device then only external_sd is affected. Well maybe not in general but thats how it is in my kitkat device. But then with this device it't even worse as the whole micro SD card becomes write protected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57171/discussion-between-p5music-and-greenapps).