# Android 4.4 new rules for accessing external storage: are lower sdk targeted apps affected?

Tags: android, sdk, storage, android-sdcard

Unfortunately my app could be broken by Android 4.4 new rules for accessing external storage.

See here: http://www.xda-developers.com/android/android-l-may-change-sd-card-access-rules/

It is compiled against Android 3.1 so I would like to know if my app is affected when runs on a 4.4 device, being targeted to level=12 sdk.

I mean, is Android 4.4 compatible with old apps that had free access to files on external storage or it breaks them even if they have lower target sdk?

Comment: probably **it will** break, else you could easily circumvent this security scheme with compiling against lower api levels

Comment: @Malte Schmitz yes but the app just could exploit the lower level sdk features so it could be a legitimate choice if they are not needed, not cicumventing the rules

Comment: The rules apply for the device. So for all apps. No way around. It has been said before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683209/android-4-4-sdcard-access-new-rules-about-saving-a-file-that-started-an-activit?noredirect=1#comment38307850_24683209